# Python: Understanding os.listdir() Method

Tags: python, image, opencv, listdir

I am still a beginner with python and I would like to understand what the following code does.

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir('E:/figs/test') if os.path.isfile(f)]
imgs = []

#read input
for f in files:
    if 'jpg' in f and 'background' not in f:
        imgs.append(cv2.imread(f))

print(imgs)
```

As it can be seen, I have inserted a path to the folder containing the images. However, when I print the content, it is empty. Please, could anyone explain what could be the reason as well as the way for solving it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `os.path.isfile(f)` is checking whether `f` is a file; but `f` is under `E:/figs/text`.   What you should try is the following:

```
main_dir = "E:/figs/test"
files = [f for f in os.listdir(main_dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(main_dir, f))]
```

As this will check the existence of the file `f` under `E:/figs/text`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have modified the codes as follows and it worked.    ```files = [f for f in os.listdir(im_path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(im_path, f))]
imgs= []
print(files)

# read input
for f in files:
    if 'jpg' in f and 'reflection' not in f and 'background' not in f:
       imgs.append(cv2.imread(os.path.join(im_path, f))) ```

Answer (score 0):

`os.listdir()`  method in python is used to get the list of all files and directories in the specified directory. If we don’t specify any directory, then list of files and directories in the current working directory will be returned.

You have to use `//` instead of `/` in your folder path

Like this:

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir('E://figs//test') if os.path.isfile(f)]
```

Try this it may run

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, replacing "/" with "//" did not change anything.