# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory pandas read csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to read all csv files in a directory and add data in a single dataframe and returns the "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'australia_annually.csv'" error reading the first file.

I've this code:

```
for filename in os.listdir('data/'):
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
if resultdf.empty:
    resultdf = df.copy(deep=True)
    df = df.iloc[0:0]
else:
    resultdf.reset_index()
    df.reset_index()
    resultdf = pd.concat([resultdf, df])
    df = df.iloc[0:0]

print(os.listdir('data/'))
```

And I've a lot files to read.
[image]

Any idea to solve it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Understanding os.listdir() Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63167612/python-understanding-os-listdir-method) - your issue is basically the same as in that question. The accepted [answer](/a/63167680) there explains "It's because `os.path.isfile(f)` is checking whether `f` is a file; but `f` is under `E:/figs/text`." In particular, you need to prepend 'data/' to `filename`, as the error message states `australia_annually.csv` doesn't exist, not that `data/australia_annually.csv` doesn't exist, which is the file you want. Also consider indents.

Comment: Print the filename and you'll see that its missing the path.

Comment: ohhh..Ok thanks!!! filename havent the full path

Answer (score 0):

The [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)  don't make it as clear as they could, but `os.listdir('data/')` will return only the filenames, not the full paths to files. you need to join your path (`'data/'`) to the filename, like so:

```
path = 'data'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    df = pd.read_csv(os.join(path, filename)
```